# How to enable IPv6 on Azure Microsoft CDN?

Tags: ipv6, azure-cdn

We want content to be available over IPv6 from Azure CDN (Service type) Microsoft CDN (azureedge.net).

How can IPv6 be enabled on the CDN profile or CDN Endpoints?

Have read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/ipv6-add-to-existing-vnet-cli but do not see how that can be applied to CDN. Do I miss something?

*(First posted this at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/640940/enable-ipv6-on-azure-cdn-azureedgenet.html but realized that SO could be a great place to reach the right audience)*

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft:

> IPv6 is enabled by default on Azure CDN depending on the client requests. If it receives IPv6 requests, IPv6 stack will be used.

However for now, their DNS servers are not available over IPv6

But the answer for the contents itself is to ask for it over IPv6 and it should just work.